# FactoryGirl callbacks with multiple has_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, infinite-loop

I have three models: Course, Level and Subject.  A course has many levels and subjects.

How do I create a course object in factory girl using callbacks without getting stuck in an infinite loop?

### factories.rb

```rb
factory :subject do
  name "Arabic"
  after_build do |subject|
    subject.courses << FactoryGirl.build(
      :course,
      :subject => subject,
      )
  end
end

factory :level do
  name "Level 1"
  after_build do |level|
    level.courses << FactoryGirl.build(
      :course,
      :level => level
      )  
  end
end

factory :course do
  name        "Intermediate Arabic 4"
  subject
  level       
end
```

With this code FactoryGirl will try and make a new subject when the course is being built from the level callback, causing a new course to be built with no level specified.....and so on.

I've tried a few things but I'm going nowhere on this one.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

I do have some advice though: don't try to do this; listen to the pain this complicated test setup gives you and try to figure out if you can simplify your domain model and isolate your models more so this is not necessary.

Comment: To be honest I'm not really sure what is good or bad practice - I thought it would be better to have multiple models and make associations between them - the minor increase in complexity at this level would make it much easier to do higher level queries and such.

Is it really that unusual to have a model with a few different has_many associations?

I'm imagining 'User has_many :posts', 'User has_many :interests' for example.

Comment: You're right - my code for factories is getting out of control.  But I'm not sure how else to model my data... a course has a bunch of attributes which I also want as relations in the database.  

Could you recommend some reading material, perhaps? I evidently need to know more about how to split up the data effectively with AR.